# Как добавить класс блоку в зависимости от комбинации радиокнопок?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Всем привет.
Есть два блока радиокнопок в каждом по 3 кнопки (Первый: 1 человек, 2 человека, Семья. Второй: 3 дня, 5 дней, 7 дней). Надо добавить класс блоку в зависимости от выбора кнопки в каждом блоке. Т.е., к примеру: 1 человек + 3 дня = красный квадрат, 1 человек + 5 дней = зелёный треугольник и т.д.
Есть код, но он работает не до конца. 7 значений срабатывают, а 2 нет.
Пример кода:

```js
var shapes = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle-up', 'parallelogram', 'parallelogram-green', 'triangle-up-green', 'circle-green', 'square-green', 'square-black']

function showShape() {
  var iShape = $('form :checked').toArray().map((n, i) => $(n).index() << i).reduce((p, c) => p | c, 0);
  $('#box').removeClass(shapes.join(' ')).addClass(shapes[iShape])
}

$('input[type="radio"]').change(showShape)

showShape()
```

```css
#box {}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}

.parallelogram {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  background: red;
}

.parallelogram-green {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
  background: green;
}

.triangle-up-green {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
}

.circle-green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.square-green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green
}

.square-black {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="1" name="form-1" type="radio" checked> 1 человек
  <input id="2" name="form-1" type="radio"> 2 человека
  <input id="3" name="form-1" type="radio"> Семья
</form>
<br>
<br>

<form>
  <input id="4" name="form-2" type="radio" checked> 3 дня
  <input id="5" name="form-2" type="radio"> 5 дней
  <input id="6" name="form-2" type="radio"> 7 дней
</form>
<br>
<br>

<div id="box">
  <div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Теперь появилась другая проблема: Понадобилось стилизовать радиокнопки. Обернул в  и всё перестало работать.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const shapes = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle-up', 'parallelogram', 'parallelogram-green', 'triangle-up-green', 'circle-green', 'square-green', 'square-black']

  function showShape() {
    const checkedIndexes = $('form :checked').toArray().map((n, i) => $(n).index());
    const iShape = checkedIndexes[0] + checkedIndexes[1] * 3;
    console.log(iShape);
    $('#box').removeClass(shapes.join(' ')).addClass(shapes[iShape])
  }
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(showShape)
  showShape()
}
```

```css
#box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}

.square {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: black;
}

.circle {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: red;
}

.triangle-up {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: green;
}

.parallelogram {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parallelogram-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.triangle-up-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.circle-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #2DD14A;
}

.square-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #2C5A77;
}

.square-black {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #53076F;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #eee;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2fcc71;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  color: hsla(215, 0%, 100%, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px hsla(150, 100%, 50%, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>ВЫБЕРИТЕ ПЛАН:</h1>
  <div style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2>Количество человек:</h2>
      <div>
        <form>
          <label for="1"><input id="1" name="form-1" type="radio" checked>1</label>
          <label for="2"><input id="2" name="form-1" type="radio">2</label>
          <label for="3"><input id="3" name="form-1" type="radio">4</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br></div>
    </div>


    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2>Количество дней:</h2>
      <div>

        <form>
          <label for="4"><input id="4" name="form-2" type="radio" checked>3</label>
          <label for="5"><input id="5" name="form-2" type="radio"> 5</label>
          <label for="6"><input id="6" name="form-2" type="radio"> 7</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br></div>
    </div>


    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я напортачил?

Comment: Во всем виноват `php`

Comment: Во всём виновата моя голова.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с вычислением индекса.

Посмотрите пример, здесь используется метод попроще.

```js
const shapes = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle-up', 'parallelogram', 'parallelogram-green', 'triangle-up-green', 'circle-green', 'square-green', 'square-black']

function showShape() {
  const checkedIndexes = $('form :checked').toArray().map((n, i) => $(n).index());
  const iShape = checkedIndexes[0] + checkedIndexes[1] * 3;
  console.log(iShape);
  $('#box').removeClass(shapes.join(' ')).addClass(shapes[iShape])
}

$('input[type="radio"]').change(showShape)

showShape()
```

```css
#box {}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}

.parallelogram {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  background: red;
}

.parallelogram-green {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
  background: green;
}

.triangle-up-green {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
}

.circle-green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.square-green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green
}

.square-black {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="1" name="form-1" type="radio" checked> 1 человек
  <input id="2" name="form-1" type="radio"> 2 человека
  <input id="3" name="form-1" type="radio"> Семья
</form>
<br>
<br>

<form>
  <input id="4" name="form-2" type="radio" checked> 3 дня
  <input id="5" name="form-2" type="radio"> 5 дней
  <input id="6" name="form-2" type="radio"> 7 дней
</form>
<br>
<br>

<div id="box">
  <div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое.

Comment: Теперь появилась другая проблема: Понадобилось стилизовать радиокнопки. Обернул в и всё перестало работать.

Comment: @Newageman Печально. Ищите ошибку.

Comment: Ищу, но без толку. Я, к сожалению, в javascript и jquery полный ноль.

Comment: @Newageman если у вас есть новый вопрос, но надо задать новый вопрос)

Comment: Понял. Думал что лучше не плодить темы. Создам тогда новый.